# Visual Studio Code - File encoding in a TFVC project while using the Diff screen

Tags: character-encoding, visual-studio-code, tfvc

It seems that my **Visual Studio Code** is ignoring the encoding that I manually set in the User Settings file.
As you can see in the following image, I added the 8th line, and that is the only modification I made. But, In the diff screen, every special character gets modified:
[image]

This is the User Setting file that I have:
[image]

The **windows1252** encoding works perfectly while editing the file, but it seems to get replaced by utf8 (standard VSCode encoding) while comparing both versions.

By the way, I am using the **Visual Studio Team Services** extension. Has anyone faced this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seemed to be a problem with the extension itself. Right now, I am using the **Azure Repos v 1.144.1** and it is working just fine.